# inverted inheritance of data members from derived to base c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

The code most have 1 base class, 2 derived classes and 2 virtual functions. in the first virtual function (redefined in the first derived class) i have to either enter 2 values to sum them, or just 1 value to use later, in the second virtual function (redefined in the second derived class) i need to either enter 2 values to substract or just one to multiply or divide with the value that was going to be used later. i dont have problms when adding or substracting, the problm is when i try to multiply or divide.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int op;
int oopp;

class base
{
protected:
    float a,b,c;
public:
    void calculo();
    void imprimir();
    virtual void datos1(){};
    virtual void datos2(){};
};

class derivada1:public base
{
public:
    void datos1();
};

class derivada2:public base
{
public:
    void datos2();
};

void derivada1::datos1()
{
    if(op==1)
        {
            cout<<"a = ";
            cin>>a;
            cout<<"b = ";
            cin>>b;
        }
    if(op==3)
        {
            cout<<"a = ";
            cin>>a;
        }
}

void derivada2::datos2()
{
    if(op==2)
        {
            cout<<"a = ";
            cin>>a;
            cout<<"b = ";
            cin>>b;
        }
    if(op==3)
        {
            cout<<"b = ";
            cin>>b;
        }
}

void base::calculo()
{
    if(op==1)
        {
            c=a+b;
        }
    if(op==2)
        {
            c=a-b;
        }
    if(op==3)
        {
            if(oopp==4)
                {
                    c=a*b;
                }
            if(oopp==5)
                {
                    c=a/b;
                }
        }
}

void base::imprimir()
{
    if(op==1)
        {
            cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;
        }
    if(op==2)
        {
            cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;
        }
    if(op==3)
        {
            if(oopp==4)
                {
                    cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;
                }
            if(oopp==5)
                {
                    cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
    base *p;
    derivada1 a;
    derivada2 b;
    cout<<"op = ";
    cin>>op;
    //1 sum
    //2 substraction
    //3 multiply or divide
    switch(op)
    {
    case 1:
        p = &a;
        p->datos1();
        p->calculo();
        p->imprimir();
        break;
    case 2:
        p = &b;
        p->datos2();
        p->calculo();
        p->imprimir();
        break;
    case 3:
        cout<<"oopp = ";
        cin>>oopp;
        switch(oopp)
        {
        case 4:
            p = &a;
            p->datos1();
            p = &b;
            p->datos2();
            p->calculo();
            p->imprimir();
        break;
        case 5:
            p = &a;
            p->datos1();
            p = &b;
            p->datos2();
            p->calculo();
            p->imprimir();
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"bye!"<<endl;
            break;
        }
    default:
        cout<<"bye!"<<endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

sorry if its too much code, i tried to reduce it as much as i could

Comment: What is the input you're using? What is actually wrong? What are you expecting?

Comment: i expect to get an answere when asking the program to do a multiplication or divition, because when i summon calculo with the object b it only uses the input from datos2, not from datos1

Comment: for example, if the input for op is 3, and then for oopp is 4, it first saves 'a' for the object a, and then 'b' for the object b, but when i try to use both with the object b and calculo, its like i never gave an input for 'a'

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: i already did that, when i summon calculo with object b, 'a' is 0 and 'b' is whatever i put when running the code

Comment: `p = &a; p->datos1();` uses one object. `p = &b; p->datos2();` uses a completely different object. `p->calculo(); p->imprimir();` since `p` has not changed these use only the second object.

Comment: and how can i use the inputs for both objects at the same time?

Comment: Why do you want/need that? The operations only use two variables and you have those two in a single object. Using multiple objects together is certainly possible but this is what books are written about not comments or answers here.

Comment: its for a school assignment lmao

Comment: the assignment its actually to calculate circuits and stuff like that, but the hw is pretty similar to what i posted

Comment: All I can say is take a step back and rethink the way you are approaching the assignment. Write out on paper how you see things working and then take another stab at some code to implement that. Do not use global variables, instead pass parameters. Do not reuse pointers to objects, keep them separate and when the objects need to interact consider if you need to pass one object to another or if you would be better off with a free function that worked with multiple objects. I don't know what you assignment is so I can't really offer more than that. Good luck!